# .htaccess rewrite rules doesn't work

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

simple question but at the moment i don't understand htaccess... so i hope you can help me.

this is my .htaccess file:

```
#RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

at the old server it works only with the first part. So if i open url like this: test.com/foo/bar
bar.php would be open if there is no index.php.
if i open url like this: test.com/foo/bar/25/3
25 and 3 ist in `$_GET['page']`.

I googled somthing and found the second part, but it should not work. he told me that he would open bar.php but didn't find this on the server. If i look in my folder there is the file.

hope someone could help, thanks a lot.

EDIT:

New Problem, the .htaccess works well but if i logged in on the side, i would redirect to the directory test.com/foo/logged... there is a new complex menu.

first i have my `$_GET` splitted:

```
$url = explode("/", $_GET['page']);
```

and this is the logged/index.php:

```
<?php if( $_SESSION) : ?>

<?php include("start.php"); ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php include(BASE_URL."/login.php"); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

this is my start.php:

```
<?php if( strlen($url[0]) > 0 ) : ?>

<?php include("packages/".$url[0]."/view/".$url[1].".php"); ?>      

<?php else: ?>

<? include "games.php"; ?>

<? endif; ?>
```

now, if i am in the logged area i can't open any menu-link like: foo/bar.
the link in start.php have to look now so: `packages/foo/view/bar.php`.

but the site is allways the same as logged/index.php...

Comment: Your missing the QSA flag in the second rewrites, so your scripts not going to receive `$_GET['page']`, your second rewrites will pass the string and look for `foo/bar/25/3.php` obviously this is not what you expect

Comment: ok thanks for the fast answer. i tried it out an exchanged the L with QSA but i also get the 404 error. Yeah you are right, i need a mixe of both rules. Or, can i edit something more at the server to open /bar as /bar.php?

Comment: L = last (means if it matches, dont check the next rewrites) QSA = Query string append (Allows you to add parameters to the url `?get=somthing`) you can use multiple flags `[L,QSA]`. Whats wrong with the first rewrites? Do you do routing logic within the script?

Comment: nothing is wrong with the first part, it will work. But i want to solut the problem with .php ending. I googled and found this solution for htaccess. At my old server, only the first part was in the htaccess, and it worked. I dont know what changes are different between both servers, i don't configure them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: ok thanks for help, but now, if click i link like this: test.com/foo/bar it tries to open test.com/foo/bar/index.php. But it should look like this: the linkt is test.com/foo/bar, and it opens test.com/foo/bar.php

Comment: If `/foo/bar/` is a directory then directory will open otherwise `/foo/bar.php` will open. Let me know if you want a different behavior .

Comment: Hm, i'm sorry but it doesn't work for me. It'll always open the index.php not the bar.php... It can't be a wrong webserver configuration, right?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is `/foo/bar/` a directory?

Comment: Is this .htaccess placed in `DocumentRoot` OR in some sub directory?

Comment: my folder structure looks so: html/test/ here is the .htaccess file in html/test/foo/ is bar.php

Comment: awesome! thank you very much! i could not vote cause i don't have 15 reputation but i checked your answer. thanks a lot

Comment: oh i'm really sorry, but here is a new problem. i post a new answer with the code... Hope you could help here too

Comment: No need to post that in answer, just edit your question and post the code.

Comment: I just read that. But didn't understand all of it since rewrite rules don't deal with PHP SESSION etc. Can you tell me in short which URL is not working for you and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: ok i fixed it. i just needed to put the second part of the .htaccess in a a new .htacess in the logged directory. now it works fine i think. thank you anyway